# Difference between おく and 中

Tags: words, meaning

Since both (oku and naka) mean 'inside', I am confused as to in which contexts they will be used.

Comment: How did you find out that all of these mean "inside"? I can't think of an example where すみ would mean "inside".

Comment: There's a sentence in my book which reads: Heya no sumi ni ookii hon-dana ga arimasu.

Comment: Aha, but here "heya no sumi" doesn't mean "_inside_ the room". Why don't you look up "sumi" in a [dictionary](http://beta.jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E3%81%99%E3%81%BF)?

Comment: Oh.. You are right, I was mistaken. It means corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`中` means "inside" or "center" in general.

`奥` means "inner(most) part".  It has more of "hidden" or "deep" feeling to it.

(Before the topic was edited) <strike>`隅` means "inside corner" (as opposed to outside corner).</strike>

Comment: I think 中 doesn't mean "center" but 中央 or 真ん中 means " center".

Comment: @YuuichiTam: 大辞泉 gives 10 meaning for なか, the first equates to "inside", the second is: 中央。まんなか。「込み合いますから—へお詰め下さい」

Comment: I think the meaning of 中 as "center" is　little used but as " inside" is usually used. Your example of 中 means "inside". If you want to say the center, you use 中央　or 真ん中